# sed - How to insert a text before a matched pattern in a file

Tags: regex, string, shell, sed, replace

I have a file a.html with the contents like the below

```
<script src="one.sample.js"/>
<script src="two.sample.js"/>
<script src="three.sample.js"/>
```

I would like to modify the above like

```
<script src="/web/test/src/one.sample.js"/>
<script src="/web/test/src/one.sample.js"/>
<script src="/web/test/src/one.sample.js"/>
```

How to have a generic pattern to replace all the occurrences at once with sed?

Comment: if you are new to sed, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources... you need to show research efforts to get help here... and I would suggest that you use html/xml parser to solve this instead of using sed

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
$ more a.html 
<body>
        <script src="one.sample.js" />
        <script src="two.sample.js" />
        <script src="three.sample.js" />
</body>
```

**Transformation:**

```
$ more htmlScriptConvertor.xslt m
::::::::::::::
htmlScriptConvertor.xslt
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//script[@src]">
        <script src="{concat('/web/test/src/',@src)}"></script>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will copy everything except the script nodes that contain a `src` attribute (you can add constraints that the attribute value must end by `.js`for example) if you need to restrict your transformation to javascript scripts.

**Output:**

```
$ xsltproc --html htmlScriptConvertor.xslt a.html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="/web/test/src/one.sample.js"/>
    <script src="/web/test/src/two.sample.js"/>
    <script src="/web/test/src/three.sample.js"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Redirect it and save it to `a_new.html`